# Create dynamic page with dynamic addresses

Tags: uri, routes

My module creates pages. These pages have dynamic addresses, such as:

- **test** -> http://www.SITENAME.com/**test** or
- **hello/world** -> http://www.SITENAME.com/**hello/world** or everything that admin adds.

How do I assign a page callback to these pages? I get the "page not found error" on these pages.

I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Confusing........... are you talking about alias? If so focus on path and autopath modules.

Comment: Have you reinvented http://drupal.org/project/pathauto ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by "my module creates pages". It sounds as if you meant to say "URLs" instead of "pages".

Anyway, if you want to link a callback to a URL, you need to implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in a custom module. See the menu_example module and its hook_menu implementation [menu_example_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/menu_example--menu_example.module/function/menu_example_menu/7) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to tell Drupal about your dynamically generated paths

Comment: That is not exact: You can use `hook_menu()` for menu paths that contains wildcards (see "node/%node" for example), and which match more than one path ("node/%node" matches "node/1," "node/1200," "node/344534545").

Comment: Agree. Yet, I think, hook_menu_alter will be more flexible.

Comment: It is not more flexible, and it is not thought for dynamic menus. Its only purpose is to alter what defined with `hook_menu()` from other modules, which is similar to the purpose of other alter hooks, such as `hook_element_info_alter()`, `hook_form_alter()`, or `hook_system_info_alter()`.

Comment: Isn't altering of other modules' menu items a definition of 'dynamic'? :)
What if module wants to generate free-form paths, like 'pagepath1', 'anotherpath/someother', 'completely/free/path'? You cannot define paths like these in hook_menu. That's what I meant by hook_menu_alter being more flexible.

Comment: The point is that: You use `hook_menu_alter()` to alter what defined in other modules, not to define you module's menus, for which you use `hook_menu()`.